# iOS 5 movie player

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit, mpmovieplayercontroller

Hi everyone i got a problem to play a video in iOS 5. When I'm building the program i get a warning "local declaration of hides instance variables" and when i run the program and tap the button i get a "SIGABRT". And i don't know what to do, all the help i can get is aprriciated!!

Thx in advance

MY .h file

```
     #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> 

    @interface MainViewController : UIViewController {

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;


}


-(IBAction)Video:(id)sender;

@end
```

MY .m file

```
    #import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end


@implementation MainViewController


-(IBAction)Video:(id)sender {

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"big-buck-bunny-clip" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
[moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local declaration of hides instance variables
```

remove the first line of your `-(IBAction)Video:(id)sender` method.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer; //this line;
```

because you already have declared such variable in your .h file.

Answer (score 0):

Means you declared the same variable names two times, one in .h file and another in .m file.